# How configure all all api url's in one angular configuration file in angular 11

Tags: angular

As an example we have 20 service classes. Suddenly backend localhost port is changed so I have to change them all in 20 service classes. How can I configure the local host port in one configuration file in angular so I have to change it only ones.

Comment: Environment file is pretty suitable for that..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app.config.ts file and keep all API related URLs there and import the file in the services. So you should have something like this

```
export class AuthenticationAPI {
  public readonly API_LOGIN = 'auth-token-url';
  public readonly API_PORT = 3000;
}

export class ProductAPI {
  public readonly .....
}
```